# Apache Tiles Configuration does not work

Tags: tiles

I set the configuration for Tiles but it only loads extended page, which is main content, but not header.jsp or footer.jsp. it doesn't make error either.

I think it doesn't apply the configuration of Tiles in action-servlet.xml but only other view resolvers...

I don't know why... What did I do wrong?

action-servlet.xml

```
<!-- tiles -->
<bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean> 
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <value>/WEB-INF/layout/layout.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" p:order="1" />

<!-- View Resolver -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="2" />
</bean>
```

layout.xml

```
<tiles-definitions>

<definition name="base" template="/WEB-INF/views/template/base.jsp">    
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp"/>
</definition>

<definition name="/" extends="base">    
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/contents/boardList.jsp" />
</definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

base.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

<!-- header -->
<tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />

<!-- contents -->
<tiles:insertAttribute name="content"/>

<!-- footer -->
<tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />

</div>
</body>
</html>
<html>
<head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not include header, footer attributes in your extended anonymous definition. Modify your layout.xml as below,

```
<tiles-definitions>

<definition name="base" template="/WEB-INF/views/template/base.jsp">    
   <put-attribute name="header" value="" />
   <put-attribute name="footer" value=""/>
</definition>

<definition name="/" extends="base">    
  <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/contents/boardList.jsp" />
  <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp" />
  <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp"/>
</definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```